# The equivalent of pointer-events:none in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a problem with wiggling bottom border pseudo css element, pointer events set to none fixes it but I have decide to go with javascript and create a span on mouse enter event and remove it on mouse leave event. with set time method, I created an acceptable animation like feeling but now back to the same problem WIGGLING. So is there an equivalent code in javascript that mimics pointer events set to none?

```html
<a class="top-link">
 <span class="title"> Title </span>
</a>
```

```css
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: solid 3px #ddd;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(4px);
  transition: ease-in 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```js
  document.querySelectorAll(".top-link").forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '<span class="border-bottom"></span>');
    el.childNodes.forEach((e) => {
      if (e.className == "border-bottom") {
        setTimeout(() => {
          e.style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
          e.style.opacity = "1";
        }, 50);
      }
    });
  });
  el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    el.childNodes.forEach((e) => {
      if (e.className == "border-bottom") {
        setTimeout(() => {
          e.style.transform = "translateY(4px)";
        }, 25);
        setTimeout(() => {
          e.style.opacity = "0.4";
        }, 50);
        setTimeout(() => {
          e.style.opacity = "0";
          e.remove();
        }, 250);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I've removed tags for `jquery`, `reactjs`, `typescript` and `frontend` as I don't see how they could help debug the code posted.  If I have erred please reinstate them and edit the question to include their significance to the problem.

Comment: There is no exact equivalent, though the closest thing would probably be `preventDefault()`, however this is very situational. For example, using `preventDefault()` on the right-click (*contextmenu*) event stops the right-click menu from appearing, much like `pointer-events: none;` would do. But for your case, you are actually adding event listeners, not blocking the default behavior. So it looks like you need a conditional statement to skip an element that you wish to not apply the event listeners to.

Comment: @traktor you maybe right about TypeScript but the other tags are accurate I think

Comment: @EssXTee My point is not blocking the event listener right away of cause I need them so the span could be created. the problem occur when the span is created and it has a space that could be pointed, then the wiggling starts if the mouse is pointed at the span.